# Setting the Selectedindex/selectedvalue of a Dropdownlist in a repeater not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater with a DropDownList in it. I set the datasource of this list in the itembound event en set the selectedindex. When I debug the selectedindex is set, but when the page is done loading for all the item the default item is selected.

This is my code:

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DataFeedItems");
        ddl.DataSource = FilterDropDownData();
        ddl.DataTextField = "ColumnName";
        ddl.DataValueField = "ColumnName";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.SelectedValue = "Select";
        ddl.SelectedIndex = 28;
    }
```

> ```
>   protected DataTable FilterDropDownData()
>     {
>         var importedFeedColums = I make the table here;
>         DataRow newRow = importedFeedColums.NewRow();
>         newRow[0] = "Selecteren";
>         importedFeedColums.Rows.Add(newRow);
>         return importedFeedColums;
>     }
> ```

I Als tried to using the Databound even of the dropdown list, but this didnt work either:

```
    protected void DataFeedItems_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList) (sender);
        ddl.SelectedValue = "Selecteren";
        ddl.Items[28].Selected = true;

    }

 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
            onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                <label><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ColumnName") %></label>                       
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DataFeedItems" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DataSource='<%# FilterDropDownData() %>'
                        DataTextField="ColumnName" DataValueField="ColumnName"   OnDataBound="DataFeedItems_DataBound" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <input id="Hidden1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ColumnName") %>' />
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

When I post the form I can get the selectedvalue and text of each DropDownList. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does FilterDropDownData() return?

Have you tried this?

```
 ddl.Items.FindByValue("Selecteren").Selected = true;
```

or

```
 ddl.Items.FindByText("Selecteren").Selected = true;
```

Comment: Could you post you whole code behind and your whole aspx page? Also, how is the FilterDropDownData() call implemented?

Comment: I just noticed that    ddl.Items.FindByText("Selecteren").Selected = true; works in IE, but not in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: In the html the option is also selected, <option value="100000000000" selected="selected">Default</option>. But the dropdown just shows a blank text in chrome, and the first item in firefox

Comment: Maybe you should try looping through the items and explicitly set Selected = false on the others

Comment: My Frontend mate had placed a function in the generic js file to reset all dropdownlist values...

Comment: Wow. That's pretty dumb. :) Best of luck with everything

Answer (score 1):

This approach will fail since a drop-down can not have multiple items selected. And setting the "Selected = true" will do exactly the same.

Only way you can set an item as selected is by using the SelectedIndex property of DropDownList.

Ex:`ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue("Selecteren"));`